# Make an html5 video buffer less before playing

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, video

When someone clicks to watch a video on my site (mp4 in an Html5 video tag) - the browser buffers a lot of it before showing it. This is not needed - the video is less than half a minute long, and has shown only half of it by the time the whole video has been downloaded.

Is there a way to tell browsers not to buffer so much?

Comment: no, but you can start caching it before they click to cut down the delay.

Comment: Do you mean buffer instead of cache?

Comment: @mason oops. You're right. Corrected now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's been a lot of discussion in the comments regarding whether this can be done, so I'll provide a Media Source-specific answer here.

**[Media Source Extensions](http://www.jwplayer.com/html5/mediasource/)**, or MSE, are a new (and not yet widely-supported) set of tools to help you control buffering and streaming with HTML5 videos. From the W3C abstract:

> This specification extends HTMLMediaElement to allow JavaScript to generate media streams for playback. Allowing JavaScript to generate streams facilitates a variety of use cases like adaptive streaming and time shifting live streams.

I'll specifically refer you to the **[SourceBuffer Object](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/#sourcebuffer)**, which has information on how audio & video track buffering is handled.

Support for MSE varies by browser and format ([source](http://www.jwplayer.com/html5/mediasource/)):

- Chrome for Desktop 34+ (MP4, WEBM)
- Chrome for Android 34+ (MP4, WEBM)
- IE 11+ on Windows 8.1 (MP4)
- IE for Windows Phone 8.1+ (MP4)
- Safari for Mac (MP4, TS)

Support for Firefox can be turned on by the user in about:config ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource)). Support has been in the works for [some time](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=778617).

There is much more that needs to be implemented in order to make use of this effectively, including video file clustering. I would recommend reading this [4-part series](http://blog.wirewax.com/building-a-media-source-html5-player/) that goes step by step into how to create a fully functional HTML5 video player utilizing everything mentioned above.

Comment: A word of warning. MediaSource is a terrible API that requires you to specify the video codecs used using a string format appended to the mime type. It's extremely difficult to find tools to extract these media codec strings. The only one I could find which produces the same string format as used by MediaSource only works with mp4 videos.

Comment: Updated link for the 1st of the 4part series mentioned
https://www.wirewax.com/blog/building-a-media-source-html5-player

Comment: I cannot believe that 4-part series starts on wirewax, part two is on aws, then it goes to squarespace (which is asking for signup or payment).  Anyone have the full 4-part series in total somewhere?

Comment: OK, for future travelers, I had to use the "Next Post" to get to the other parts.  If you use the link at the bottom that is part of the article, their link is broken and goes all over the place.

Comment: As of today, the links to all 4 posts: [part 1](https://www.wirewax.com/blog/building-a-media-source-html5-player/), [part 2](https://www.wirewax.com/blog/building-a-media-source-html5-player-with-adaptive-streaming-25/), [part 3](https://www.wirewax.com/blog/building-a-media-source-html5-player-with-adaptive-streaming-34/), [part 4](https://www.wirewax.com/blog/building-a-media-source-html5-player-with-adaptive-streaming-44/)

Answer (score 7):

> Is there a way to tell browsers not to buffer so much?

The buffering process is initially controlled completely by the client <sup>*</sup>  (see update below on how this can be controlled programatically) and we can only hint to it what we need using the `preload` attribute.

Using `preload = "auto"` (or just a blank string) indicates to the browser that it is likely that the video will be played completely:

[image: table]

Even with this the client can override it if it finds it necessary.
[source](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/video.html#attr-media-preload)

**Update**

*) There is up and coming **[Media Source Extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Source_Extensions)** (thanks @Tim McClure) which *do* allow programmatic control of buffering. The support varies - [source](http://www.jwplayer.com/html5/mediasource/):

- Internet Explorer from version 11 on Windows 8 (MP4). (2013 October)
- Google Chrome since early 2013, also on Android (MP4, WEBM).
- Safari 8 on OS X (MP4, TS).

It can be enabled in Firefox under flags (about:config).

For more details on how to use this, see this **[longer four part series](http://blog.wirewax.com/building-a-media-source-html5-player/)** (from Tim McClure in comments).

**[Specification details](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/)**

Comment: Thanks. But what would `preload = "auto"` help in this scenario? (Or was that intended as just additional information?)

Comment: @ispiro it's only additional info related to the buffering as this is the point at where the buffer need to preload. Not using auto will for example hint that only metadata is needed (or no data at all) meaning only length/dimension is available at the time of play being invoked. Using auto will increase the chance of video data being available at play.

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg I'm not sure that this is entirely true. I believe that using [MSE](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/) combined with clustering video files allow you to have a much greater level of control over buffering.

Comment: @TimMcClure MSE seems very interesting. Unfortunately, dated 7. April this year and seem to have no support* in any browsers yet (?)  *) http://caniuse.com/#search=Media%20Source

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg True, MSE spec is still draft, but supported by Chrome, Safari and IE11 (MP4 only). It can be _enabled_ in Firefox. Youtube currently implements it when the browser supports it. Very good write-up [here](http://blog.wirewax.com/building-a-media-source-html5-player/) (it's a 4-part series). I would say that it's a good idea to at least implement where possible, as you only gain greater control over user experience. Hopefully, support becomes more widespread in the future.

Comment: @TimMcClure yeah, this is a good solution. I'll include this in the answer as an option at least. Thanks!

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg Re: your new edits - I believe that it is only IE11 that only supports MP4 - I've only used webm when working with MSE.

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg [this](http://www.jwplayer.com/html5/mediasource/) is a good reference.

Comment: @TimMcClure I feel am getting too much credit in my answer. Consider posting an answer with these details so credit will be due.

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg heh should've just done that instead. I've submitted my answer.

Answer (score 5):

If your primary concern is getting the video to play sooner, you can start buffering sooner by using the [preload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974759%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) attribute.

```
<video controls preload="auto">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: @mason controlling buffering processes is a huge positive and is something that you control when building HTML5 video players. For example, adaptive streaming takes whatever the browser creator intended and throws it out the window - BUT this allows you to change between video renditions, pre-buffer certain files, etc.

Comment: @TimMcClure So you're saying there's a way to tell the browser how much to buffer? If so, please share it.

Comment: @mason you can start by learning about [Media Source Extensions](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/), specifically the [SourceBuffer Object](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/#sourcebuffer), although that's only the beginning. I would recommend reading [this](http://blog.wirewax.com/building-a-media-source-html5-player/) - there are four parts in that series.

Comment: @TimMcClure I don't do enough video work to make learning about that worth my time to learn just so I can answer someone's question. But if you are knowledgeable about it - then go ahead and answer the question

Comment: @mason I'll refer you to the other answer.