# How to stop download video in HTML5 player

Tags: javascript, html, video, download

I have multiple HTML5 videos `<video>` on one page. When I play first, it starts downloading. But when I pause or stop it, download continues. When I play next video on the same page, there are two video downloads in the same time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make an html5 video buffer less before playing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636740/make-an-html5-video-buffer-less-before-playing)

Answer (score 2):

set the attribut preload="none" in the video tags or preload="metadata" if you want the length and other data upfront.

Answer (score 0):

Question is similar as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636740/make-an-html5-video-buffer-less-before-playing). Try to use [Media Source Extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Source_Extensions).