# Stop video buffering while playing

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video

when i play a video on website.It continuously shows buffering.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<video autoplay="" class="video" loop="" muted="">
  <source src="/assets/video/Newport-beach-video.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> 
  Your browser does not support video.
</video>
```

is there a way to load video fast? or stop buffering?

Comment: Please Visit here i think you got the solution [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071872/html5-video-force-abort-of-buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071872/html5-video-force-abort-of-buffering)

Comment: i think Try this `preload="none" controls="controls"`

Comment: I tried.But it still shows buffering.It only shows buffering in chrome browser

Comment: please remove other attribute and check [it like this example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_preload)

Comment: no effect.still the same.does any one know any good video player which works without buffering

Answer (score 0):

Please try this https://jsfiddle.net/dxb89n9j/ if its not work as per your requirements ping me

```html
 <video  autoplay="" class="video" loop="" muted=""> 
      <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm type=video/webm> 
      <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv type=video/ogg> 
      <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
      <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.3gp type=video/3gp>
    </video>
```

Comment: Okay share Your Fiddle

Comment: @Swati i think please check this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636740/make-an-html5-video-buffer-less-before-playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636740/make-an-html5-video-buffer-less-before-playing) coz i think this is browser issue

Answer (score 0):

Here are some optimizing techniques for Video.

- If Video is very large, try to re-encode it and use video with smaller bit rate
- Try to reduce audio bitrate, Remove Audio channel or Use mono channel