# How to live-stream raw PCM through HTML5 audio element

Tags: html5-audio, live-streaming, pcm, media-source

I have a *.NET web application* where I am receiving in my C# controller *real-time audio* from another application in the form of *raw PCM bytes*. I would like to stream this audio real-time through the [HTML5 audio element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio). It's no problem adding wav header to the raw PCM bytes, and stream the data through the audio element as audio/wav.

The problem, as similarly stated in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636740/make-an-html5-video-buffer-less-before-playing), is that **the buffering amount tends to be way too much** for what is supposed to be "real-time" streaming. The audio doesn't begin playing until about 25 seconds worth of data is read (which takes about 5-6 seconds).

I've looked into using *MSE ([Media Source Extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Source_Extensions))* to be able to manually handle the buffering amount. But it does not seem to support wav format currently ([source](https://github.com/w3c/media-source/issues/55)).

Changing the data to a more supported format like mp3 by encoding the data real-time within C# has had its own caveats (i.e. [padding 0-bytes](http://lame.sourceforge.net/tech-FAQ.txt)), so I would like to **avoid this if possible**.

**Is there a viable way around this** until MSE adds support for pcm/wav?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [ScriptProcessorNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScriptProcessorNode) in the Web Audio API to play arbitrary PCM samples at very low latency.  Then, you can manage the buffering however you want.

Just convert your samples to 32-bit floating point at ±1.0.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Also, for anyone interested, [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/501521/How-to-convert-between-most-audio-formats-in-NET) has a nice section *Changing PCM Bit Depth* on how to convert samples to 32-bit floating point that I'm finding very useful for this.