# Streaming low latency avc/h264 video to a browser with MSE

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, mp4, h.264, mse

I am currently encoding live video and streaming to the browser. 
I encode rgb->vuy->h264->Wrap in (MP4 ISO BMFF Byte Stream Format spec, section 3)-> websocket to client. 
first package is initialization data from ftyp to moov tag.

And from there on I am sending moof and mdat tags to the client. 
And I stream the video.

No matter how many frames are in mdat chunk. The MSE always buffers the data to have seamless play. How can one overwrite this using MSE.

I read somewhere that there is a way mdat understands that it is a live steaming webm chunk. But I do not know if such think exist for mp4 or exists altogether.

Comment: I found this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636740/make-an-html5-video-buffer-less-before-playing

but there is not a real answer

Comment: How are you creating the mp4, and how are you controlling the chunk size?

Comment: i use Microsoft sinker(Fragmented version), Then loop and change some values in the mp4 Tags such as tfdt trun and stuff to make it Spec 3 compliant so that MSE wont complain. I have full control over the encoder. So The more frames I put to the sinker the more chunks I get. But the issue is on the client side. even if I write 2 frames per chunk(mdat) there is still a latency as MSE need to buffer before start rendering.

Comment: I have never hear of Microsoft sinker. And google returns no results. Are you getting one moof every two frames? Or just one mdat every two frames? Can you post a sample file?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sending moof once per one frame and it works.

Comment: Yeah, in my experience moof for each frame is the best way to reduce latency. I actually checked Chrome sources and they also tread moofs as fragments that should be completely received to start decoding.

Comment: I send ftyp and moov initially. 
Then I send (moof and mdat) . mdat might have one or more frames. Is that right? I am getting about 1 or 2s delay on local network. 
I am trying to get to 0.2/0.3s.  I send about 20 fps. 
If i get up to 30 FPS, tcp buffers eventually fill up. My encode is fast, I encode with Intel or Nvidia harware encoders. So I can get up to 60 fps easy on encode side. 
I am streaming my desktop so  I can see the cursor being late. screen resolution is 1080x1920  So frame size matters too.  What resolution are you guys sending?

Comment: A related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54186634/sending-periodic-metadata-in-fragmented-live-mp4-stream